# Estimating Present Bond Value without YTM using yield curve rates

Tags: finance, interpolation, economics

Suppose I have a bond where I know the par value, coupon rate, and maturity date as well as the daily Yield Curve Rates given [here](https://home.treasury.gov/sites/default/files/interest-rates/yield.xml)

How can I go about estimating the ytm needed to determine the present value of the bond with only this information?

To ask another way, how would I estimate the rate of, say, a bond with 14 years left in its maturity when the treasury only give rates for the 10 year and 20 year. Is it some kind of interpolation between those closest points or the entire yield curve? I've done some simple linear /log regressions and I can't get calculations consistent with the bond values fidelity/vanguard are giving me.

I've been pulling my hair out a bit over this, so thank you in advance!